# XML echo name with PHP

Tags: php, xml, echo

I have file.xml

```
<header name="1">
<title>
<text1 name="001"/>
<text2 name="002"/>
</title>
</header>
```

And php:

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents("file.xml");
echo htmlspecialchars($xml);
?>
```

How to echo simply text from names, so result must be: 001 - 002

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Sorry, i cant find the answer there/ Can you explain please?

Comment: Which library did you attempt to use?

Comment: file.xml is external on another site. i use jquery

Comment: Which PHP library did you try out to process file.xml?

Comment: sorry, its pure php. I dont use libraries yet

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by pure PHP but PHP has built-in libraries for interacting with XML. Have you tried anything from that link I posted?